# Can't open setting in Ubuntu 22.04 Lts

Tags: gnome, software-center, samba

**Can't open settings in Ubuntu 22.04 Lts**

I have try to reinstall gnome-control-center, but still doesn't work

> Gnome-control-center: symbol lookup error:
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamdb-common.so.0: undefined
> symbol: ldb_msg_append_string, version LDB_2.4.4

I'm new to using ubuntu, I don't have much knowledge about it